# Join operator in rails unable to be queried

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails

In my welcome_controller, in the def home, I have a definition

```
@my_search = Restaurant.joins(:inspection).where(cuisine: params[:cuisine], zipcode: params[:zipcode], totalscore: params[:lower..:higher])
```

And in my html.erb

```
<%= form_tag home_path do %>
  <%= label_tag :cuisine, "Cuisine:" %>
  <%= text_field_tag (:cuisine) %>

  <%= label_tag :zipcode, "Zipcode:" %>
  <%= text_field_tag (:zipcode) %>

  <%= label_tag :lower, "lowerScore:" %>
  <%= text_field_tag (:lower) %>

  <%= label_tag :higher, "higherScore:" %>
  <%= text_field_tag (:higher) %>

  <%= submit_tag("Search") %>
<% end %>
```

The totalscore column resides in inspection. But since I have joined them, they should be in the same table. However, I get this error

```
mysql2::Error: Unknown column 'restaurant.totalscore' in 'where clause': SELECT `restaurant`.* FROM `restaurant` INNER JOIN `inspection` ON `inspection`.`rid` = `restaurant`.`rid` WHERE `restaurant`.`cuisine` IS NULL AND `restaurant`.`zipcode` IS NULL AND `restaurant`.`totalscore` IS NULL
```

This is a really weird error. Can anyone give me advice here?

Thank you!

From the restaurant model

```
has_many :inspection, foreign_key: 'rid'
```

From the inspection model

```
belongs_to :restaurant, foreign_key: 'rid'
```

Comment: What is the relation between restaurant and inspection?

Comment: inspection belongs to one restaurant and restaurant has many inspections

Comment: Try this `@my_search = Restaurant.joins(:inspections).where(cuisine: params[:cuisine], zipcode: params[:zipcode], inspections: { totalscore: params[:lower..:higher] })`

Comment: Association named 'inspections' was not found on Restaurant; perhaps you misspelled it? 
Couldn't find the inspection table

Comment: Sorry. Try this `@my_search = Restaurant.joins(:inspection).where(cuisine: params[:cuisine], zipcode: params[:zipcode], inspections: { totalscore: params[:lower..:higher] })`

Comment: Actually my first approach is right. The error is due to associations. `has_many :inspection, foreign_key: 'rid'` should be `has_many :inspections, foreign_key: 'rid'`

Comment: well, actually it worked. All the forms are up. But whats weird is when I try to search now (by hitting the submit button), it doesn't show me any results.

Comment: May be you should ask it as another question.

Answer (score 0):

The following query should fix your problem

```
@my_search = Restaurant.joins(:inspections).where(cuisine: params[:cuisine], zipcode: params[:zipcode], inspections: { totalscore: params[:lower..:higher] })
```

And also as per the ***naming conventions***, the ***association name*** for `has_many` should be ***plural***. So fix that in your code.

```
has_many :inspection, foreign_key: 'rid'
```

to

```
has_many :inspections, foreign_key: 'rid'
```